# Disable lock screen in Android 5 Lollipop

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, lockscreen, device-admin, device-policy-manager

Upto API 20, device lock screen can be programatically handled via DevicePolicyManager resetPassword(PIN, DevicePolicyManager.RESET_PASSWORD_REQUIRE_ENTRY)

To Lock, PIN != "" and
To UnLock, PIN == ""

But from android 5 (API 21) setting PIN to "" is not working. This is further discussed on 
  https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=1765 and https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78272

The deprecated      KeyguardLock disableKeyguard() / reenableKeyguard() are also not working as expected all the time.

From API 17, setKeyguardDisabledFeatures in DeviceAdminInfo with USES_POLICY_DISABLE_KEYGUARD_FEATURES is also not working as stated in documentation [ref](http://developer-android.ir/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#setKeyguardDisabledFeatures(android.content.ComponentName,%20int)).

Is there any workaround for this to work in Android 5+ devices?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any work around, but it seems to be fixed in 5.1:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78272#c18

Comment: according to the change log for android 5.1, https://paste.teknik.io/1010 seems resetPassword("") is fixed.